# Select specific input with multiple ID to parse as form

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

Hello fellow developers

I am student developing a hybrid mobile app using cordova for a school project and I encountered an issue which i need assistance with.

Background info about my dead-end.

1. I am trying to display 15 images from my server to the interface for user to select
2. I successfully displayed the image with unique value and unique id using the input tag. The outcome is (input id='1' value='1') (It will increment based on the number of images found on my server).
3. **This is where i hit a dead knot...** I realised that jQuery selector can only focus on one ID and value $(#ID).val() But what I am trying to achieve here is user select the image input and the appropriate ID is recorded to be parse via an AJAX call to my server and recorded to the DB.

```js
function showAvatarResult(arr) {
    //if i is less than the total number of artefacts, increment by 1
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var avatarimage;
        var avatarid;
       
        avatarid = arr[i].avatarid;
        avatarimage = "<input type='image' id='" + avatarid +"' value='" + avatarid +"' src='" + serverURL() + "/images/avatars/" + arr[i].image + "' width=17%' height='17%'  />";


        
        $("#avatar").append(avatarimage);

    }
}
```

```html
<form name="RegisterForm1" id="RegisterForm1">
<center>
<div id="avatar"></div>
</center>

</form>
```

```js
function registerGroup() {
    username = $("#newusername").val();
    password = $("#newpassword").val();
    email = $("#emailaddress").val();
    school = $("#school").val();
    contactdetails = $("#contactdetails").val();
    groupname = $("#newgroupname").val();
    member1 = $("#member1").val();
    member2 = $("#member2").val();
    member3 = $("#member3").val();
    member4 = $("#member4").val();
    member5 = $("#member5").val();
    member6 = $("#member6").val();
    member7 = $("#member7").val();
    member8 = $("#member8").val();
    avatarid = //stuck here

    url = serverURL() + "/register.php"; 

    var JSONObject = {
        "username": username,
        "password": password,
        "email": email,
        "school": school,
        "phone": contactdetails,

        "groupname": groupname,
        "leader": member1,
        "member2": member2,
        "member3": member3,
        "member4": member4,
        "member5": member5,
        "member6": member6,
        "member7": member7,
        "member8": member8,
        "avatarid": //this is where I am stuck
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        data: JSONObject,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (arr) {
            _getRegisterGroupResult(arr); 
        }, error: function () {
            validationMsg();
        }
    });   
}
```

Comment: _"I realised that jQuery selector can only focus on one ID"_ - Yes, that's the point of selecting elements by id, you can select multiple ids separated by a comma (`"#id_1, #id_2"`), please [edit] the post and include a valid [mcve]

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Comment: @AlonEitan Hi I am sorry was editing the post with the code snippet

Comment: @Infinite_Dots NP. Why can't you select the elements by some specific class name and then iterate over the elements to create the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a class to each image input like `<input class='image-input' type='image' id=...` (this should be the same class name on all image inputs) and then use the following script to set a variable equal to the input's ID when clicked:

```
<script>

var selectedImageId;

$('.image-input').click(function(){
    selectedImageId = $(this).attr('id');
});

</script>
```

Then, in your `registerGroup()` function, access the variable like this:

```
...
member8 = $("#member8").val();
avatarid = selectedImageId;

url = serverURL() + "/register.php"; 
...

...
    "member8": member8,
    "avatarid": avatarid
};
...
```

I would do some input validation to ensure you have valid inputs before you send the data in the AJAX request.

Comment: _"I would do some input validation to ensure you have valid inputs before you send the data in the AJAX request."_ -- I hope you _also_ validate on the server. Validating on the client is to assist the user and to avoid wasting a round-trip when the client knows the data is not valid, but ... The Server **must not** trust what the client sends it.